# How to redirect a page in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I want to redirect a page if some condition returns true. I have no idea how to do this. Can any one provide me with an example?

Or is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `redirect()` function from the [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html/).

EDIT:
load the url helper:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
if (condition == TRUE) {
   redirect('new_page');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use redirect() helper function.

Example :

```
$this->load->helper('url');

if ($logged_in == FALSE)
{
     redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code after your **if** statement

```
redirect(site_url('/index'));
```

I hope that is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->helper('url');
redirect(base_url('controller/function'));
```

or

```
redirect(base_url().'controller/function');
```

or

```
redirect('controller/function');
```